# hibernate 4.3.0.Final causes a ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: oracle, hibernate, persistence.xml

What would I need to specify in the persistence.xml in order to avoid Oracle complaining about ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded?

This error occurs after migrating from Hibernate 4.2.6 to 4.3.0

Comment: No, seriously, hibernate 4.3.0 Final does actually leak cursors.  This is a known bug.  See the bug report here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8811 and the forum discussion here: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1030371.  I have to provide this information in a comment since apparently questions marked duplicate cannot be answered.

Comment: Note that there is now a 4.3.1 release that fixes this issue.  Release 4.3.0 certainly wasn't "Final", it should have been labeled "Unusable".